# How to have 'other' as an option in dropdown list?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to have a dropdown list which the list is retrieved from the database. the list will have 'other' as an option at the bottom of the list. How can do that?

currently this is my code but it not working

```
SELECT id, contactName 
FROM ( 
       SELECT id as id, c_contactName as contactName 
       FROM app_fd_crm_cust_cntct 
       UNION
       SELECT 'others' as id, 'Others' as contactName
) a
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN id <> 'others' THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
         END
         , contactName asc
```

Comment: I would suggest to add the option in `PHP` not in the query as it adds a level of complexity that is not needed.

Update your original question showing the `PHP` code you use to generate the dropdown

Comment: hi, you could use a [select union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266833/populate-select-drop-down-with-data-from-two-mysql-queries?rq=1) or add it in on the server-side in PHP